# How can I show videos Like LinkedIn post like this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

LinkedIn example Post

[image]

Hey Guys I am new to flutter , I'm getting single videos nor multiple Videos link from the API link according to the user uploads. So I want to create a Responsible widget. Which want to change according to the API data. please see the Image mark below.

Comment: you just need to use map variable, and set the map data from fetch data you got from api, and use itembuilder to show video base on howmany index the map had